# JQuery.when multiple JSON variables

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, when-js

I have this code which retrieves JSON using `$.getJSON()` from 2 URLs and saves the results as variables. I then use `$.when()` and `then()` to get the data from these variables. However, this only works when I do one at a time, each with it's own `$.when()`, and does not work when I use both.

```
var player = $.getJSON("http://api.hivemc.com/v1/player/" + $user + "/timv");
        var game = $.getJSON("http://api.hivemc.com/v1/game/timv");

        $.when(player,game).then(function(maindata, data){
            $('#1').text(maindata.total_points);
            $('#2').text(maindata.i_points);
            $('#3').text(maindata.t_points);
            $('#4').text(maindata.d_points);
            $('#5').text(maindata.role_points);
            $('#6').text(maindata.most_points);

            if(maindata.detectivebook == true)
                $('#7').text("Yes");
            else
                $('#7').text("No");

            $flare = maindata.active_flareupgrade;
            $flare = $flare.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $flare.slice(1).toLowerCase();
            $('#8').text($flare);
            $('#9').text(maindata.title);
            var d = new Date(maindata.lastlogin * 1000);
            var n = d.toISOString(); 
            $('#10').text(d.getDate() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getFullYear());
        });
```

The console error I get is:

> jquery-latest.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of 
>      undefined
>      at Function.each (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
>      at Object. (dr:112)
>      at Function.each (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
>      at Object. (dr:108)
>      at Object. (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
>      at j (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
>      at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
>      at x (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
>      at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-latest.min.js:4)`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Do you receive any error in console?

Comment: Well I am using 000Webhost to host my site while developing and I'm not sure how to view the console

Comment: Press F12 in the browser, or right click an element and click 'Inspect'

Comment: I will put the error in the main post, though I'm not sure how much sense it will make without the full code

Comment: you can also add a second function argument to the `then` for handling error: `then(function success(maindata, data){ /*...*/ }, function error(params){ /*...*/ })` (the params are set depending on how the fail() is called in the promise)

Comment: when i run your request, i don't have the error, however, one of the 2 requests gets a 404 response because i don't have a valid user to put in the url, can you give me a valid test user? (i have added an error function like i said in my previous comment, and this is the error function that gets called)

Comment: @Kaddath a test user could be `b0xx3r`, thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the reason why: when you use `then`, the params you declare in your success function are not the data itself, but an array containing the data, the status string and the XHR object. So in your case `maindata` gets `[Object, "success", Object]`.
Replace this part of the code with the following and it should work (additionnally, maybe there should be a check to do on the status before getting the data):

```
$.when(player,game).then(function(mainresponse, response){
    var maindata = mainresponse[0];
    var data = response[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!